# Extension Chrome, Next js, chrome storage, remote API

Tags: javascript, api, next.js, google-chrome-extension

First time building a Chrome extension, doing it with Next JS, while requiring chrome Storage to store an URL, and a remote API route.

I have followed documentation, tutorials such as https://swizec.com/blog/building-browser-extensions-with-nextjs/, but I am still blocked when trying to access the API route:

index-edac6fa049906610.js:1 Error submitting URL: TypeError: Failed to fetch, tried with Axios and I get an network error.

I have well set up my next.config.js file to open the remote API:

```html
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: '/api/:path*',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' },
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
            value: 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT'
          },
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            value:
              'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```